# Button to trigger drawRect to redraw a view

Tags: ios, xcode, drawrect, ibaction, setneedsdisplay

I have a VC with a subview. At the `subview level` I have a button. I want the button to result in the view being updated.

The `IBAction` code is in the VC. All it currently does is toggle a `BOOL` value.

Back in the subview drawRect: method is the code that tests the `BOOL` and changes the view accordingly.

My observation is that when the button is pressed, the IBAction code runs, toggles the `BOOL`, but the `drawRect:` method doesn't get called.

I tried calling drawRect manually (not good practice and didn't work). I tried calling setNeedsDisplay but that too didn't work (couldn't figure out how to reference the subview, which is created programmatically).

Suggestions welcome.

IBAction code is trivial but included below:

```
- (IBAction)rotateWindowButtonWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    // just flip the boolean here. Need to make the code change in drawRect: in top2View.m
    if ([myGlobals gWinVertical])
        [myGlobals setGWinVertical:NO];
    else
        [myGlobals setGWinVertical:YES];
    // Hoping this would force a redraw, but bounds have to change...:(
    //_top2ViewOutlet.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
}
```

Comment: Prettier shortcut: [myGlobals setGWinVertical:![myGlobals gWinVertical]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened - there was an answer above that solved my issue but now it's gone? Anyway - the answer is to create the button programmatically and then I can include the method at the subview level where drawRect: is, and using setNeedsDisplay to repaint the screen. That vs. using IB and having the IBAction code at the VC level.

Answer (score 10):

to issue a drawRect call, call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view you changed.. the OS will call drawRect on it and affected overlapping views automatically.

in your case I think

`[self.view setNeedsDisplay]`